# JMeter testing with BIRT report

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, load, report, birt

I'm writing scripts for Load Testing for an IBM maximo application. This Application creates some BIRT reports and displays them in the same browser window but in a different tab.

I'm clueless how to open these with JMeter http Request. I copied the same request in JMeter as I found in Fiddler, but encountered some errors in the response.

My fiddler request is as follows:

`reportFile=asset_meters.rptdesign&reportNum=1170&__newrun=true&comments=&fromEmail=no&where=%25EF%25BF%258E%25EF%25BF%25B9%2522%2513%2508%25136%25EF%25BE%25A8J%25EF%25BE%25A8%2501%25EF%25BF%25B5%25EF%25BE%2591%2527%25EF%25BF%2593y%25EF%25BF%25ACU%2523%2518x%251B%25EF%25BF%2580%25EF%25BF%2592%25EF%25BF%25BAh%250C%25EF%25BF%25A8o%25EF%25BE%25B6%2517%25EF%25BF%25A4*%25EF%25BE%25A0o%25EF%25BE%258BN%25EF%25BF%258A%25EF%25BE%25A8b3%25EF%25BF%25A8%250F%2505%25EF%25BE%25BFcU%2522&mroOrg=QRC&redir=%2Fmaximo%2Freport%2F%3F__report%3Dasset_meters.rptdesign%26appname%3DASSET%26__requestid%3D1550750628853%26uisessionid%3D17617%26csrftoken%3D8dkj0qdgphnd347jreegt21lj5&mroApp=ASSET&maxPass=%25EF%25BE%25AA%25EF%25BE%25A5%2529%25EF%25BF%2592h%2510%25EF%25BE%2596%25EF%25BE%2594&redirParams=repositoryType%3DEnterprise&customrptServerLogonPass=&smtpHost=localhost&localTZ=Africa%2FAlgiers&locale=en_US&p_asset=M100000000003&reportDesc=QR+-+Asset+Meters+%26+Installed+Information&mroUniqueKey=190221160348853_29579&extendedFields=false&Email_Choice=PDF&emails=&userName=maxadmin&ParmUserName=maxdemo&reportFolder=ASSET&qbrDisplayWhere=%28assetnum+like+%27%25M100000000003%25%27%29&schema=maxdemo&reportType=BIRT&appname=ASSET&ParmPassword=%25EF%25BE%25AA%25EF%25BE%25A5%2529%25EF%25BF%2592h%2510%25EF%25BE%2596%25EF%25BE%2594&mroSite=METRO&paramdelimiter=%7C%7C&paramstring=appHierarchy%3DASSET&__scheduleType=immediate&__reportname=asset_meters.rptdesign&isDuplex=0&baseTable=ASSET&customserverURL=&__overwrite=new&baseUrl=http%3A%2F%2F172.17.43.71%3A9080`

JMeter Request is:

`reportFile=asset_meters.rptdesign&reportNum=1170&__newrun=true&comments=&fromEmail=no&where=%25EF%25BF%258E%25EF%25BF%25B9%2522%2513%2508%25136%25EF%25BE%25A8J%25EF%25BE%25A8%2501%25EF%25BF%25B5%25EF%25BE%2591%2527%25EF%25BF%2593y%25EF%25BF%25ACU%2523%2518x%251B%25EF%25BF%2580%25EF%25BF%2592%25EF%25BF%25BAh%250C%25EF%25BF%25A8o%25EF%25BE%25B6%2517%25EF%25BF%25A4*%25EF%25BE%25A0o%25EF%25BE%258BN%25EF%25BF%258A%25EF%25BE%25A8b3%25EF%25BF%25A8%250F%2505%25EF%25BE%25BFcU%2522&mroOrg=QRC&redir=%2Fmaximo%2Freport%2F%3F__report%3Dasset_meters.rptdesign%26appname%3DASSET%26__requestid%3D1550750847369%26uisessionid%3D17618%26csrftoken%3Detbohmkqeg5ufvpr1tvrv9qp9a&mroApp=ASSET&maxPass=%25EF%25BE%25AA%25EF%25BE%25A5%2529%25EF%25BF%2592h%2510%25EF%25BE%2596%25EF%25BE%2594&redirParams=repositoryType%3DEnterprise&customrptServerLogonPass=&smtpHost=localhost&localTZ=Africa%2FAlgiers&locale=en_US&p_asset=M100000000003&reportDesc=QR+-+Asset+Meters+%26+Installed+Information&mroUniqueKey=190221160727369_29580&extendedFields=false&Email_Choice=PDF&emails=&userName=maxadmin&ParmUserName=maxdemo&reportFolder=ASSET&qbrDisplayWhere=%28assetnum+like+%27%25M100000000003%25%27%29&schema=maxdemo&reportType=BIRT&appname=ASSET&ParmPassword=%25EF%25BE%25AA%25EF%25BE%25A5%2529%25EF%25BF%2592h%2510%25EF%25BE%2596%25EF%25BE%2594&mroSite=METRO&paramdelimiter=%7C%7C&paramstring=appHierarchy%3DASSET&__scheduleType=immediate&__reportname=asset_meters.rptdesign&isDuplex=0&baseTable=ASSET&customserverURL=&__overwrite=new&baseUrl=http%3A%2F%2F172.17.43.71%3A9080`

The corresponding responses:

Fiddler response is:

[image: fiddler Response]

JMeter response is:

[image: Jmeter Response]

I checked in the server logs, but found nothing suspicious.

Then I observed in the JSON tab (in the Fiddler request) something like:

[image]

Is this is the bottleneck reason for me?

How can I embed this in my JMeter request?

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that you need to implement [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), to wit extract the dynamic values for the following parameters:

- `__requestid`
- `csrftoken`
- `mroUniqueKey`
- etc.

  1. Check previous response and carefully inspect it looking for the values of the (at least) aforementioned parameters
  2. Extract them using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and store into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
  3. Replace hard-coded (recorded?) values in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) with the values from step 2

Given you send the same request in JMeter as browser does (apart from dynamic parameters) you should be able to see the same response.

Check out [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) article to learn more about "correlation" concept

Comment: Hi Dmriti,  all 3 parameters u mentioned above ,i already fetched from previous response trhrough RegEx..any other thought....i m still stuck :(  any thought about json=reportfile in fiddler (JSON tab in request)....waiting fr response